# Calling a get method in another class without creating an object in Java

Tags: java

Hi I am a beginner in Java programming. As the title says, I am trying to call a get method in another class without creating an object. The get method can not be static as I am accessing private in field in a given class. I know that I can access a regular method without creating the object if the method is static, but I cant do this with a simple get method. I know that this is not possible, but are there alternatives or some other way to get around this? I have three classes. One super class and the other two extends this class. I have a List in one of the subclasses and I am trying to access the get method of that list in the other subclass (not sure if this is relevant). The list is instantiated in the constructor of the given class. I dont really have any code besides the get methods so there is not much to show in code really. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
public class A{}

public class B{ 
private List<A> list; 
private B() {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}
public int getList() {
    return list;
}
}

public class C{
I want to access getList method here. 
}
```

Comment: The first couple of sentences sound like this is impossible. Can you show your code and what you are currently attempting.

Comment: Why do you need that? Probably, providing some code will help better understand your issue?

Comment: Smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question where you're asking how to do something, but where your total approach may be wrong. Better to tell the details of the problem rather than how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: maybe take an instance of class B in class C's constructor (not sure if this helps)

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function without creating an object does not make sense. Methods are meant to process the data which is packed inside an object.

If you have two subclasses and you are trying to store something in that list then you simply have to `pull-up` your list function or `list` object in your super-class.

Inside the super class constructor, You can initialize the list. Everytime you create a new object(in this case a subclass object), it will have it's own list.

However, what you are trying to do is totally wrong and simply not possible.

```
public class A extends B{}

public abstract class B{ 
private List<B> list; 

public B() {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}
protected ArrayList<B> getList() {
    return list;
}
}

public class C extends B{
   //You can now call list method.
}
```

// I did not compile it but it should work and this is how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

This question makes no sense.

By definition, class functions can be static (independent of instances) or non-static (per-instance). You mentioned that the get function can't be static, therefore it must be instance-bound - this type of function would be used to safely access instance values.

Private variables are usually internal class instance variables. If you aren't creating an object, there are no instances to run the get function on.

Suppose you have a class Fruit with private instance variables Color, Flavor, and Weight - and "get" functions for each of them. A static "get" function makes no sense - are you going to retrieve the flavor of all known Fruits despite having no idea what fruits they represent? Nonsense! You need to have instances of the class in which case you can use a get function to read off the instance variables.